# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)

Tags: ipython, opencv3.0

When I try to import cv2 in IPython , I am getting this error-

**ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)**

I have opencv 3.0, ubuntu 14.04, python 3.4.
I searched online but couldn't get any answer.

Comment: I started getting the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 with opencv 3.1.0-dev and python 3.5 all of a sudden. I was working fine for months, but then it stopped...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python3 libraries usually can be found in:
**/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages**

I found out that the library **cv2.cpython-34m.so** is needed for Python3.4.
But this file wasn't be contained in my default library directory.

In my environment, this library was stored in /usr/**local**/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/

So I created a symbolic link.
Try it with:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-34m.so

python3
>>> import cv2
```

I hope, this helps you

Comment: HI julian, 
   I made the changes, in my case i am working on Python 3.5 in Mac environment. The cv2.so file was kept in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so. I ran the command to link. The output is 
ln: ./cv2.so: File exists
Post that when i try to import cv2, the PyCharm(Python IDE) is giving me again "ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)"

Can you please do let me know how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using opencv library for python2 in python3.

Check your PYTHONPATH by typing

`echo $PYTHONPATH`

and see there is correct path for python3.

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

I define PYTHONPATH at the end of `~/.bashrc` file. Modify it if you are loading python2's library.

After `source ~/.bashrc` or restart terminal, check PYTHONPATH again

It solves my problem.