# Error importing cv2 in Python after opencv installation

Tags: python, opencv

I've successfully installed OpenCV, but when I try to import it in Python, I get the errors below.

In Python 2.7, I'm getting this

```
[imukunya@li165-244 site-packages]$ python

Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 30 2018, 23:45:53)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import cv2
>>> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

In Python 3.6, I'm getting this error

```
[imukunya@li165-244 site-packages]$ python3.6

Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 10 2018, 17:08:37)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import cv2

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)
```

I've already tried installing NumPy using `$~python3 -m pip install numpy -I`

Comment: The NumPy error is happening with Python 2.7, so you should install using python2 instead of python3. For your Python3 problem, did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36070215/4228275)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to execute the below command. Then please verify whether your code is working.

**python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python**