# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_MyMath)

Tags: python

python version: 3.11
I'm trying to write some cpp extension for python. Here's my code

add.cpp

```cpp
#include <Python.h>

int inc(int a) {
    return a + 1;
}

int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

static PyObject * _inc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int _a;
    int res;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &_a))
        return NULL;
    res = inc(_a);
    return PyLong_FromLong(res);
}

static PyObject* _add(PyObject *self, PyObject* args){
    int _a, _b;
    int res;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &_a, &_b))
        return NULL;
    res = add(_a, _b);
    return PyLong_FromLong(res);
}

static PyMethodDef MathModuleMethods[] = {
    {
        "inc",
        _inc,
        METH_VARARGS,
        "increase by one"
    },
     {
        "add",
        _add,
        METH_VARARGS,
        "add a and b"
    },
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef mymath = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "mymath",
    NULL,
    -1,
    MathModuleMethods
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_mymath(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&mymath);
}
```

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup,Extension

mm = 'MyMath'
setup(name=mm,ext_modules=[Extension(mm,sources=['add.cpp'])])
```

Then I run `python setup.py develop`. It complie the .so file successfully.When I am in the same directory using python interpreter to `import MyMath as MM`. It gives the following error:

```py
Python 3.11.5 (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:54:46) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MyMath
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_MyMath)
>>>
```

I've already check the PYTHONPATH is correct according to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070215/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-pyinit-cv2)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you call your module `mymath` and sometimes you call it `MyMath`. You need to be consistent. Specifically, change `PyInit_mymath` to `PyInit_MyMath` and you should be fine.

In `setup.py` you said the name of the module is `MyMath` and so python is looking for a symbol called `PyInit_MyMath` in the `.so` file. However, in your `.cpp` you called it `PyInit_mymath` and so it is not detected by python and the module cannot be loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I used to think PyInit_XXX, XXX should be consistent with the PyModuleDef obj instead of the name parameter of setup.

Comment: My personal preference is to use `snake_case` names for modules rather than `CamelCase` names. Keeping everything lowercase helps avoid this problem.

Comment: With respect to the name for the `PyModuleDef` struct. Python doesn't know or care about that. Python uses `PyInit_MyMath()` to get a reference to that struct.